# decode error when I use scrapy to crawl json

Tags: json, scrapy, decode, python-3.6

I want to use scrapy to crawl a json.Here is my code:

```
class zhangjiaweiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "zhangjiawei"
    start_urls = [
        "https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/api/columns/zhangjiawei/posts?limit=20&offset="
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(1):
            url = self.start_urls[0] + str(i * 20)
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonbody = json.loads(response.body.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
        print(jsonbody)
```

But when I run it,I get errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\soft\python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\code\python\spider\zhihuzhuanlan\zhihuzhuanlan\spiders\zhangjiaweispider.py", line 24, in parse
    jsonbody = json.loads(response.body.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
  File "d:\soft\python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "d:\soft\python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "d:\soft\python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I tried to print `response.body.decode()`, but got error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: 
invalid start byte
```

if I print `response.body.decode('utf-8','ignore')` they are Garbled.
I thought this error may be caused by `response.body`'s decode. But I don't know how to resolve this problem.

my `setting.py`:

```
BOT_NAME = 'zhihuzhuanlan'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['zhihuzhuanlan.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'zhihuzhuanlan.spiders'

DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language':'zh-TW,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6',
    'USER-AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',
}

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'zhihuzhuanlan.pipelines.ArticleDataBasePipeline': 5,
}
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
# linux pip install MySQL-python
DATABASE = {'drivername': 'mysql',
            'host': '192.168.203.95',
            'port': '3306',
            'username': 'root',
            'password': 'Password',
            'database': 'spider',
            'query': {'charset': 'utf8'}}
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

Comment: it runs ok here, can you share your settings file?

Comment: Ok,thank you.Can I see your whole code?

Comment: What version of Python and Scrapy are you using?

Comment: I tried it now with Scrapy 1.5.0 on both Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.4.3 with just setting `USER_AGENT` string and it worked as expected, without any error.

Comment: oh,I tried to delete other headers and it worked right.Thank you.